# How to generate basic HTML pages with static content using PHP and mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql, qr-code

I have recently started to write code in PHP for a specific project. I am using the *PHPQRCode* library to generate QR codes from a sample database created in MYSQL. I am running all of this on a XAMPP server hosted on my machine.

The sample entries from my db are given below:[image]

Also I will post the snippet of the code I have written so far . This code fetches the data from the db and convert it into a QRCode. Comments have been added at required lines.

```
<?php
include "phpqrcode/qrlib.php";
// This library helps in generating QR Code 
// db_name is quickcodedatabase
define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
define("DB_DATABASE", "quickcodedatabase");

$connect = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

//actual sql query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM quickcodetable";
$result = $connect->query($sql);
$count = 1;
// count is used here to generate sequential names for output image files.
if ($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    // output data of each row
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $rowdata = "Name: " . $row["s_name"] . " Address = " . $row["s_address"] . " Amount = " . $row["amount"];

        echo nl2br($rowdata . "\n");

        $file_name = "test_mid" . $count . ".png";
        $count++;
        //count is used to generate sequential file names
        QRcode::png($rowdata, $file_name);

        echo nl2br("<img src='../$file_name'>" . "\n");

    }
}
else
{
    echo "No results";
}

mysqli_close($connect);

?>
```

The output I get after running the above code is:

[image]

Now what I want to achieve is **to get(or export) each QR and the data associated with it on a separate HTML file**. So, in my case I will have three newly created HTML files after I run the code.

As I am pretty new to PHP I am not able to figure out how to do this. I looked at some of the related questions posted here but could most of them involved use of some COM objects which I am totally unaware about. I dont care about the formatting on the output pages as long as I get the details related to each database entry exported on a separate HTML page along with the corresponding QR code.

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
$n = $_POST['n'];
$p = $_POST['p'];
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","mysql username","mysql password","database name");
    if($con->query("insert into users(name,password)values('$n','$p')")){
header("location:index.php");
}
}
?>
<form method="post" action="file.php">
<input type="text" name="n" placeholder="Name"/>
<input type="password" name="p"  placeholder="Password"/>
<input type="submit" value="add"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Slightly change this piece of code as follows. It will save the html text with qr code image to an html file on each iteration with the name "test_mid" . $count . ".html"

```
 while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $rowdata = "Name: " . $row["s_name"] . " Address = " . $row["s_address"] . " Amount = " . $row["amount"];

    $rowdata=nl2br($rowdata . "\n");

    $file_name = "test_mid" . $count . ".png";
    $count++;
    //count is used to generate sequential file names
    QRcode::png($rowdata, $file_name);

    $rowdata.=nl2br("<img src='../$file_name'>" . "\n");
    file_put_contents("test_mid" . $count . ".html",$rowdata);

}
```